# object signatures are identical, typescript shows warning

Tags: typescript

I am not sure why typescript is barking at me when I try to use my own created type from express' types.

> Argument of type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'.

> Property 'req' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'Context'.

The type signatures are identical, i'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.
How can I pass `req` and `res` to `getStatus`?
Routes.ts

```
import getStatus from "../routes/status";
 
export default function routes({ app }: Context): void {  
  app.get("/_status", ({ req, res }: Context) => getStatus(req, res));  
} // barking at me here                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Status.ts

```
import { Context } from "../../utils/Context";
import express from "express";

export default async function getStatus({req}: Context, { res }: Context): Promise<Express.Response> {
//....
}
```

Context.ts

```
import { Request, Response, Application } from "express";
export type Context = {
  req: Request;
  res: Response;
  app: Application;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue is that you're double destructuring.  The anonymous function parameter already extracts the *req* and *res* from Context.  The two fields are passed to **getStatus**, but it is expecting to get passed two Context parameters and extract *req* and *res* again.

I think the best thing to do is change the signature of **getStatus** so Request and Response are the types of the two parameters.

```
export default async function getStatus(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Express.Response> {
   //....
}
```

Alternatively, just past context as one parameter.

```
app.get("/_status", getStatus)
```

```
export default async function getStatus({ req, res }: Context): Promise<Express.Response> {
   //....
}
```

Comment: Why isn't object destructuring working from `Context`?

Comment: It is, but in your example you're passing the destructured parameters to getStatus.  You're double destructuring.

Comment: since i'm setting the type to `Context` which contains these param-names, its not double? How else am I gonna use it? How is parameter gonna know what type-member to pick? I can't just do `app.get("/", ({wtf, wtf2}:Context)`

Comment: I expanded on my answer, hopefully it makes more sense.  You already destructured Context in the app.get callback, you don't need to do it again.  Either pass in the parameters, or pass the Context and destructure in the function, don't do it two places.

Comment: `I think the best thing to do is change the signature of getStatus so Request and Response are the types of the two parameters.`, then what is the point of creating new type? What you are proposing is in my mind contradicting the languages features.

Comment: You don't have to create any new types.  Just import Request and Response type.  IMO, it's better to follow the law of Demeter, but either solution is viable.

Comment: But there is purpose in doing so. For e.g. I need to do `Request & {session: Express.Session}` eventually... I'll accept regardless.